# is there any new api to create functionality like iBook

Tags: iphone, ios4, ibooks

As we all knew that apple has put new iBook to read ebooks and for that they have provided so many good functionalities.

my questions is have they provided any new api or sample to add such kind of functionality in our applications??

another things like page curling effect for the web views ,as it is not possible to give such effect on the xhtml files.

If I am not wrong , they have provided 1500 different API's for developers, so if any one do have any idea then please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. They have added new subclass of UIViewController which supports same functionality as iBook. Check out the following link.

[UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPageViewController)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this two link can help you

[PDF Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

[Epub Reader](http://www.ideveloperworld.blogspot.com/2011/02/epub-reader.html)